# vidstab installed on Ubuntu, Melt can't find it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, melt

I am trying to stabilize a shaky video with melt.

i have installed the vidstab plugin shown below.

```
:~$ apt-cache search  vidstab
libvidstab-dev - Video stabilization library.
libvidstab1.0 - Video stabilization library.
```

But i don't see melt is picking it as shown below.

```
:~$ melt -query "filters" | grep stab
- videostab
- videostab2
```

its not listing vidstab, but shows only depreciated filters.

How do i make vidstab filter accessible to melt.

Comment: is this linux / unix question? Not tagged correctly

Comment: @JoeFerndz Tags updated